# Bootstrap-Sass gem not working with Rails 4 on MacOSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

i have recently encountered an error when i run rails server after installing and following the steps mentioned in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

## What's the mising Piece??

**Gemfile**

```
group :assets do
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

    # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
end
```

**styles.css.scss**

```
@import 'bootstrap'
```

**Error**

> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.

Comment: are you sure you ran `bundle install` and restarted your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by adding this to my config.ru file

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'bootstrap-sass' #require statement of bootstrap-sass
run Rails.application
```